# PHP Session with Memcached and AWS

Tags: php, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I have an application running on Elastic Beanstalk and just used ElastiCache to launch memcached. However, I am still trying to figure out how to use it to save a session. From what I have read I thought I had everything correct, but I'm not sure why it's not working.

My code:

```
<?php
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'memcached');
ini_set('session.save_path', 'xxxxx.nrrxny.cfg.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:11211');
session_start(); 

$_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views']+1;
echo "Pageviews = ". $_SESSION['views'];

echo "<h3>Show All Variables</h3>";
foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val)
echo $key." ".$val."<br/>";
?>
```

Comment: Have you added the necessary rule to the security group to allow connections to memcache?

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot to do that. @SamV Thanks